# Not able to write data to Snowflake database using ODBC connector from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to read data from Azure Data Lake Storage and write to Snowflake database using Azure Data Factory pipeline.
But I am getting below error. At the same time I am able to read it from Snowflake. I do have write privilege at the database side. I have Integration Runtime installed on the Azure VM, ODBC driver installed on the VM. Able to establish the connection successfully.

```
Message': 'Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=SystemErrorOdbcWriteError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [07009] [Snowflake][ODBC] (10670) Invalid descriptor index, descriptor record does not exist, or descriptor record was not properly initialized.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.Exceptions.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [07009] [Snowflake][ODBC] (10670) Invalid descriptor index, descriptor record does not exist, or descriptor record was not properly initialized.,Source=Snowflake,'',
'EventType': 0,
'Category': 5,
'Data': {
'FailedOdbcDbOperation': 'ERROR [07009] [Snowflake][ODBC] (10670) Invalid descriptor index, descriptor record does not exist, or descriptor record was not properly initialized.',
'FailureInitiator': 'Sink'
},
'MsgId': null,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature for integrating with this tool being worked on. I do not have an eta.

Comment: Would you be able to share the details of this feature and how to track about the implementation progress.. ?

Comment: @Akash Snowflake does not have a way to provide direct external updates on developing features at this time, but you can certainly ask your Snowflake Account Team for an update on this connector whenever you meet with them.  Also, our Community does provide notifications about new features when they are ready to be made publicly available.  You can signup here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/community-help

Answer (score 0):

I just created a temp solution that could trigger a COPY function from snowflake. You would have to export your data as a file in to a Azure Staging area from ADF then use this function to make a call to Snowflake to ingest the new files.

It essentially allows you to pass connection parameters plus a SQL command to snowflake from ADF.

https://github.com/NickAkincilar/Snowflake-Azure-DataFactory-Connector

[snowflake-datawarehouse]